# SKLightNode not working on real device [iPhone 5]

Tags: iphone, sprite-kit, ios-simulator, ios8

I've set up a minimalistic project [here](http://override-apps.com/wp-content/uploads/iOS8_Test.zip) which simply adds a red square and - after tapping the screen - a light source lighting it. On simulator it runs fine, but on my iPhone 5 the square just becomes invisible as soon as the light source gets added to the node tree.

Can anyone test this on other, real devices and give feedback? Any solutions? It's driving me crazy.

Here's the scene's code:

```
SKLightNode* lightNode;

@implementation GameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    //Add some node to be lit
    SKSpriteNode* node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
    node.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2.0, self.size.height/2.0);
    node.lightingBitMask = 1;
    [self addChild:node];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //Add a light node to light the object
    if (!lightNode) {
        lightNode = [SKLightNode node];
        lightNode.categoryBitMask = 1;
        [self addChild:lightNode];
    }
    lightNode.position = [((UITouch*)[touches anyObject]) locationInNode:self];
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    lightNode.position = [((UITouch*)[touches anyObject]) locationInNode:self];
}

@end
```

Comment: I take it the iPhone 5 is running iOS 8?

Comment: Yes, iOS8 GM seed. Generating shadows has worked before in a far more complex project, so the device is capable of using light/shadows as part of SpriteKit.

Comment: I just installed the official iOS 8 on an iPad 3rd Gen and it works as it should! Does the GM seed differ from the "official" release version?

Comment: Installing iOS 8 release version did not make a difference.

Comment: GM seed *is* the release version, just made available a few days earlier for developers

Comment: Thought so, thanks for the info. Well it definitely doesn't work on iPhone 5, but on iPad 3rd Gen. I'm out of devices.

Comment: Hmmm try with a fixed position for lightNode, or don't set it at all.

Comment: Been there, done that.

Comment: same problem here - iPhone 5 iOS 8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in iOS8. I've experienced the same problem and sent a bugreport to Apple. 
SKLightNode does not seems to work well on an iPhone5. I've tried on iPhone6 (ok), iPhone5s (ok), iPhone5 (not working - black screen), iPod5 (ok), iPad Mini Retina (ok), ipad2 (ok).