# How do I alpha-mask a SKSpriteNode?

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, mask, skeffectnode

I know there's `SKCropNode`, but it will only fully in- or exclude pixels based on an alpha threshold of the `maskNode`. What I already tried is using the `SKEffectNode` with a `CIBlendWithAlphaMask` filter, but the result I'm getting is invisible and I also wouldn't be sure on how to move the mask around. Here's the code:

```
SKSpriteNode* overlay = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Overlay.png"];
//...
SKEffectNode* blendNode = [[SKEffectNode alloc] init];
blendNode.filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBlendWithAlphaMask"];

UIImage* maskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MaskImage.png"];
[blendNode.filter setValue:[maskImage CIImage] forKey:@"inputMaskImage"];

[blendNode addChild:overlay];
[self addChild:blendNode];
```

I already had figured out the perfect solution, using a `SKLightNode` to light the texture and then blend it into the framebuffer using `SKBlendModeAdd`, but for some reason it won't work on iPhone 5 ([here's a related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25912880/sklightnode-not-working-on-real-device-iphone-5)). I'm aware of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242303/how-to-create-an-alpha-mask-in-ios-using-sprite-kit) too, which didn't help either.

Any solution to properly alpha-mask a `SKSpriteNode` would be greatly appreciated!
Running iOS 8.

Comment: CIImage was nil, it now masks but I still don't know how to move the mask around...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Using a dynamically generated `CIImage` as mask does the trick. It can be created by a CIFilter, using whatever gradient or image you need as mask, and setting the `inputCenter` property to the position you want.